# How to handle invalid inputs while displaying Game menus?

Tags: c++, loops

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() { //Program starts
    cout << "-------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "Welcome to Ninjas vs. Samurais!" << endl; //The intro
    cout << "-------------------------------" << endl;

    string newAdventure;
    string chosenKind;

    cout << "Hello, new solder! Are you ready for your adventure to begin,       yes or no?\n"; //Asks you if you are ready

    cin >> newAdventure;//Takes in if you are ready or not

    if (newAdventure == "yes" || newAdventure == "Yes" || newAdventure ==    "Yes!") { //Asks if they are ready
        cout << "Great!\n" << endl;
    }
    else if (newAdventure == "no" || newAdventure == "No" || newAdventure ==     "No!") { //Asks if they are ready
        cout << "Too bad!\n" << endl;

    }
    else {
        cout << "Please type a yes or no answer!\n";
    }  
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

If the user didn't input a valid answer, how could I make them restart the question? Would I have to use a loop? If so, how would I do that?

Comment: @pfnuesel what I mean is that if the user doesn't enter a valid answer, how could I ask the question again?

Comment: You will need a while or any other type of loop with exit condition. You will need to check the condition before entering the loop next time

Comment: use do-while loop. It is an exit control loop that is best served for displaying game menus.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a condition like this:

```
while(true)    
{

cout << "Hello, new solder! Are you ready for your adventure to begin,       yes or no?\n"; //Asks you if you are ready

cin >> newAdventure;//Takes in if you are ready or not

if (newAdventure == "yes" || newAdventure == "Yes" || newAdventure ==    "Yes!") { //Asks if they are ready
    cout << "Great!\n" << endl;
    break;
}
else if (newAdventure == "no" || newAdventure == "No" || newAdventure ==     "No!") { //Asks if they are ready
    cout << "Too bad!\n" << endl;
    break;
}
else {
    cout << "Please type a yes or no answer!\n";
}  

}
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for your responses

Answer (score 0):

Yes you would have to use a loop. Something like:

```
while(cin >> newAdventure)//Takes in if you are ready or not
  {
    if (newAdventure == "yes" || newAdventure == "Yes" || newAdventure ==    "Yes!") { //Asks if they are ready
        cout << "Great!\n" << endl;
        break;
    }
    else if (newAdventure == "no" || newAdventure == "No" || newAdventure ==     "No!") { //Asks if they are ready
        cout << "Too bad!\n" << endl;
        break;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Please type a yes or no answer!\n";
    }  
  }
```

The `break` keyword will exit the loop once your answer is valid, otherwise, it keeps going.